# Undefined symbol sun.awt.image.CachingSurfaceManager on JIDE common layer

Tags: java, netbeans, jide

I've just downloaded the JIDE common layer and I'm not able to build it because it can't find the `CachingSurfaceManager` class.

I'm trying to build this using Netbeans and the latest version of java sdk (downloaded yesterday). Should I try eclipse? I don't think that will solve the problem as I'm not able to  find the class in the java documentation either.

I thought it could be from java 6 and not 7 (which is the one I've downloaded).

[This page](http://www.findjar.com/class/sun/awt/image/CachingSurfaceManager.html) says its in rt.jar and I can't find it in there either...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find the `CachingSurfaceManager` class in the `sun.awt.image` package of a JDK 1.6. I was not able to find it in 1.7. So, I would suggest you try to compile and run your project with a JDK 1.6 distribution.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to compile under JDK 7 (and run with it), just comment out all the lines in the if statement. We had to use a non-public API here in order to implement a feature.

```
  if (!SystemInfo.isJdk7Above()) {
     // comment all lines out in this if statement.   
  }
```